# Golang. Ошибка An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: golang, websocket

есть бек на ГО, пишет в веб сокет

```golang
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
      return true
    },
  }

// ..................

http.HandleFunc("/notifications", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
        if err != nil {
            logrus.Panic(err)
        }


    })
```

На фронте

```
conn = new WebSocket("ws://host:2020/notifications");
    conn.onmessage = function (event) {
        if(event.data != "") {
            newMessage(JSON.parse(event.data));
        }
    };
```

и вот иногда срабатывает logrus.Panic(err) с такой ошибкой

```
Ошибка записи сокета: write tcp 10.3.0.14:2020->10.2.1.87:58691: wsasend: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

из-за чего это может быть, что-то с сетью?

Comment: Шиндовс?  Антивирус?

Comment: да винда, есть конечно антивир, но странно то, что оно то работает, но периодически вот такая бяка